# Не происходит redirect на пост

Tags: django

views.py:

```
class Postcreate(View):
    def get(self,request):
        form =Postform()
        return render(request,'foundation/Post_create.html',context={'form':form})
    def post(self,request):
        bound_form=Postform(request.POST)
        if bound_form.is_valid():
            new_post=bound_form.save()
            return redirect(new_post)
        return render(request,'foundation/Post_create.html',context={'form': bound_form})
```

у меня происходит показ лишь заполненной формы:

html формы:

```
{% extends 'foundation/base.html' %}
{% block title %}
    Create Post - {{block.super}}
{% endblock %}


{% block content %}
    <form action="{% url 'postcreate_url' %}" method="post" >
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for field in form %}
            <div class="form-group">
                {% if field.errors %}
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    {{ field.errors}}
                </div>
                {% endif %}
                {{ field.label}}
                {{ field}}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Create Post</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

forms.py:

```
class Postform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Post
        fields=['title','sometext','tags']
        widgets={
            'title':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'tags': forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'sometext':forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control'})
        }

    def clean_sometext(self):
        new_text = self.cleaned_data['title'].lower
        if new_text =='':
            raise ValidationError('title may not be')
        if Post.objects.filter(title__iexact=new_text).count():
            raise ValidationError('title must be unique We have it"{}" it yet'.format(new_text))
        return new_text
```

ну и models.py мб там ошибка :

```
from django.db import models
from django.shortcuts import reverse

# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_index=True)
    sometext=models.CharField(max_length=50,db_index=True)
    tags=models.ManyToManyField('Tag',blank=True, related_name='posts')
    date_pub=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('postdetail_url',kwargs={'sometext':self.sometext})


class Tag(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    sometext=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('tag_url',kwargs={'title':self.title})

    def _str_(self):
        return self.title
```

логи в консоли powershell при нажатии create post :

```
[22/Aug/2019 13:33:04] "POST /greetings/post/create/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3626
```

то что приходит я поставлю ток значения:

```
value="title 1"
value="body body body"
value="Djnago"
[22/Aug/2019 14:30:50] "POST /greetings/post/create/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3635
```

Comment: Объект создаётся вообще? Попробуйте что-то вроде - `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('postdetail_url', args=(new_post.sometext, )))`

Comment: Также ничего не происходит значит объект не создаётся тогда в чём ошибка?

Comment: я добавил лог консоли мб кто-то разбирается

Comment: так посмотрите в бд, создаётся ли он? Если нет, то смотрите, что приходит в `request.POST`

Comment: судя по всему, дело в `tags`

Comment: Информация в bound_form приходит

Comment: Так у вас же `tags` имеет связь `MTM` а вы определяете его, как текстовое поле... Посмотрите сюда - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/fields/#multiplechoicefield . Как минимум, должен приходить список значений, но никак не строка.

Comment: Ну а как тогда исправить?

Comment: Поменял на SelectMultiple ничего не меняется

Comment: при создании получаем <tr><th><label for="id_tags">Tags:</label></th><td><select name="tags" class="form-control" id="id_tags" multiple>
  <option value="1" selected>Tag object (1)</option></select></td></tr>

Comment: и что? почему форма невалидна, смотрите...

Comment: Происходит ошибка что в названии больше 50 символов хотя я ввёл 2

Answer (score 0):

```
class Postcreate(View):
    def get(self,request):
        form =Postform()
        return render(request,'foundation/Post_create.html',context={'form':form})
    def post(self,request):
        bound_form=Postform(request.POST)
        if bound_form.is_valid():
            new_post=bound_form.save()
            return redirect(new_post)
        return render(request,'foundation/Post_create.html',context={'form': bound_form})
```

вам нужно написать
вместо `return redirect(new_post)`

```
return redirect(reverse('название приложения:new_post')
```